# Retrieve data from synchronised data extension to a sendlog data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, data-synchronization

I would like to retrieve the sends and some data from Synchronised Data Extension in a sendlog data extension. Indeed, more than the sends I would like to retrieve :

1. the contacts ID who have received the emails
2. From the synchronized DE 'contacts' I would like to retrieve the Account Id
3. From the synchronized DE 'accounts' I would like to retrieve the GIE code

The subscriber key is the same than the Salesforce Contact ID
The SF accounts contains SF contacts.

I tried this code :

```
select
sl.SubscriberKey,
sl.SubId,
sl.BatchID,
sl.JobId,
sl.ContactId,
sl.CodeGie,
sl.AccountId,
CASE WHEN min(b.EventDate) is not null THEN 'N' ELSE 'O' END as RECEPTION,
CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), s.EventDate) AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time' as EventDate
from [SendLog] sl
left join _sent s on s.SubscriberID = sl.SubID and sl.JobID = s.JobID and sl.BatchID = s.BatchID
left join _bounce b on b.SubscriberID = sl.SubID and sl.JobID = b.JobID and sl.BatchID = b.BatchID
left join ent.Contact_Salesforce c on c._ContactKey = sl.SubscriberKey and c.AccountId = sl.AccountId
left join ent.Account_Salesforce a on a.SixNergieCodeGIE__c = sl.CodeGie 
group by sl.SubscriberKey, sl.ContactId, sl.SubId, sl.BatchID, sl.JobId, s.EventDate, sl.CodeGie, sl.AccountId
```

I did have results but not the GIE code neither the Account ID.

Hereby are the contact details

[image]

Comment: Are you storing Account Id and CodeGie in the SendLog? Because if you are then why join anything at all?

Comment: @zuzannamj, I have added these 2 fields in the Sendlog and the DE I wanted to create from this query but the value is not stored in these DE. It is stored in synchronized DE

Comment: @zuzannamj, I have split my query in three activities in my automation : the first one with the send activity to retrieve the sends, the second to retrieve the contacts and the accounts matching with the subscriber key from the contacts synchronized DE and the last one to retrieve the GIE code from the accounts synchronized DE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case those values are not stored in your SendLog, rather in the Synchronised Data Extensions, you have to change the table prefixes and the join logic. Try something like this:

```sql
select
sl.SubscriberKey,
sl.SubId,
sl.BatchID,
sl.JobId,
sl.ContactId,
a.CodeGie,
c.AccountId,
CASE WHEN min(b.EventDate) is not null THEN 'N' ELSE 'O' END as RECEPTION,
CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), s.EventDate) AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time' as EventDate
from [SendLog] sl
left join _sent s on s.SubscriberID = sl.SubID and sl.JobID = s.JobID and sl.BatchID = s.BatchID
left join _bounce b on b.SubscriberID = sl.SubID and sl.JobID = b.JobID and sl.BatchID = b.BatchID
left join ent.Contact_Salesforce c on c._ContactKey = sl.SubscriberKey
left join ent.Account_Salesforce a c.AccountId = a.AccountId
group by sl.SubscriberKey, sl.ContactId, sl.SubId, sl.BatchID, sl.JobId, s.EventDate, a.CodeGie, c.AccountId
```

I'm unable to test it because I don't have such data in my account but the above should work more or less.

Comment: Thanks @zuzannamj, I have adapted the query and it worked perfectly well